# Can forwarding address be provided by e-mail for landlord to return security deposit?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, tenant, evidence, british-columbia

If a landlord does not return a tenant's damage deposit in 15 days from the later of the move out date or receiving a forwarding address, tenant may go after him for double. If the forwarding address for mail is provided in e-mail or by a messaging app (such as Whatsapp, which has read receipts) is this enough? Or must the tenant use registered mail and then wait 15 days?

Relevant Sections of the tenancy Act:

https://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/02078_01#section38
https://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/02078_01#section88

Answer (score 1):

§88 gives an exhaustive list of legal ways to deliver the written notice. Each and every one of them involves delivery of a physical piece of paper, including fax transmission to a number provided by a recipient. Apart from direct hand-over, ordinary mail is acceptable so registered mail is not required. Email and phone-based messaging do not constitute legal notice having been given.

Answer (score -2):

Depends upon your goal.  If your goal is the return of the security deposit, then anything that is acceptable to the landlord will work.  Kiss-o-gram, smoke signals, phone calls or whatever.  If the goal is to get damages, then your references are clear: paper or fax (fax numbers can be purely digital).